# How to set regular expression parameter constraints for Route float parameter on Lumen

Tags: laravel, lumen

I tried to Lumen API for GPS Tracking Project. the Router can't allow to pass float parameter

```
$router->get('api/{lat}', function ($lat){
    return $lat;
})->where('lat','.*');
```

how to pass Flot Parameter on Lumen micro-Framework

Comment: You can try it `\d*\..\d*`.

Comment: \d*\..\d* this code not working..

Answer (score 0):

I thought Laravel was the same as Lumen at first, but I was wrong. :(

First, it does not support `where(<pattern>)`, so you have to do this. ([doc](https://lumen.laravel.com/docs/5.8/routing#parameters-regular-expression-constraints))

```
$router->get('api/{lat:\d*\..\d*}', function ($lat) {
    return $lat;
});
```

Next, you can't use `php -S localhost:8000 -t public` to run, because `xxx.xxx` will be treated as a static file

You have two ways to run it, `php -S localhost:8000 public/index.php` or http server.

[image]